# How to replace a element in list of objects from another list

Tags: java, list, collections

I have a List of Images

```
List<Image> images = getImages();
```

Image.java

```
public class Image {
    private String imageId;

    // getter and setter methods
    // ...
}
```

And I have a `List<String> imageIds` to replace the `imageId` in each `Image` object. What would be the best way to do it?

Comment: Can you please explain 'And I have a List<String> images to replace the imageId in each Image'? I am not sure what do you mean by replace here.

Comment: how are you identifying the relationship between each imageId and each Image object?

Comment: I need some more explanation here.

Comment: I need to replace imageId in all Image objects. For that I have List<String> with same size.

Comment: What is the order of imageId List? same as Image List?

Comment: this can lead to improper assignment of id's to the Image object. If that isn't your concern you can see already posted answers here.

Comment: Yes imageId List and Image List has same order

Comment: @vivek you should mention that in your question. This is an impotent part to provide an answer.

Comment: @Ruchira Gayan Ranaweera What if the two Lists are not in same order?

Comment: @vicky you have to give ID's based on the relationship between Image and Id. May be there are more fields related to Id in Image like name, modified date. you have to know the order else you may refer different image.

Answer (score 1):

I think traversing the `List<Image>` and for each element call the imageID's setter will just works fine.

Even if there is a way to do it with less code, it probably uses traversing fundementally.

Answer (score 0):

Iterate over the Images list and call `setImageId(imageId)` on it.

```
Iterator<String> imageIDs = imageIds.iterator();
for(Image image : images){
    image.setImageId(imageIDs.next());
}
```

Since both are List I am assuming order is important as it is inserted.

Answer (score 0):

You have mention in the comment both List has same order, So you can try this.

```
    List<String> imageIds=new ArrayList<>();
    List<Image> images = new ArrayList<>();
    for(Image img:images){
       img.setImageId(imageIds.iterator().next());
    }
```

Comment: I don't think `imageIds.iterator().next()` is what you mean to do. ; )

Answer (score 0):

You question sounds strange. It's not very clear, but if you need to add/remove/replace elements in the list, you should use [ListIterator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ListIterator.html). It has a [set](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ListIterator.html#set%28E%29) method, which allows to replace elements.

Comment: If question is not clear, you can post a comment bellow the question to clarify the question. This is kind of comment than an answer.